# Spring batch not writing to ExecutionContext mongo metadata collection after upgrading to version 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch with metadata stored in mongo DB stored under the below collections

```
JobInstance
JobExecution
StepExecution
ExecutionContext
Sequences
```

When I upgraded the Spring batch from version 3 to 4, batch framework is not writing metadata records into ExecutionContext collection. Job is running fine and it is storing the metadata into remaining collections without any issues.

Here is the MongoExecutionContextDao that we created

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.ExecutionContextDao;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.NumberUtils;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

@Repository
public class MongoExecutionContextDao extends AbstractMongoDao implements ExecutionContextDao {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        super.init();

        getCollection().createIndex(
                new Document().append(STEP_EXECUTION_ID_KEY, 1)
                        .append(JOB_EXECUTION_ID_KEY, 1)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public ExecutionContext getExecutionContext(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        return getExecutionContext(JOB_EXECUTION_ID_KEY, jobExecution.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public ExecutionContext getExecutionContext(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return getExecutionContext(STEP_EXECUTION_ID_KEY, stepExecution.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void saveExecutionContext(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        saveOrUpdateExecutionContext(JOB_EXECUTION_ID_KEY, jobExecution.getId(), jobExecution.getExecutionContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void saveExecutionContext(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        saveOrUpdateExecutionContext(STEP_EXECUTION_ID_KEY, stepExecution.getId(), stepExecution.getExecutionContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateExecutionContext(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        saveOrUpdateExecutionContext(JOB_EXECUTION_ID_KEY, jobExecution.getId(), jobExecution.getExecutionContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateExecutionContext(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        saveOrUpdateExecutionContext(STEP_EXECUTION_ID_KEY, stepExecution.getId(), stepExecution.getExecutionContext());
    }

    private void saveOrUpdateExecutionContext(String executionIdKey, Long executionId, ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        Assert.notNull(executionId, "ExecutionId must not be null.");
        Assert.notNull(executionContext, "The ExecutionContext must not be null.");

        Document dbObject = new Document(executionIdKey, executionId);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : executionContext.entrySet()) {
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            String key = entry.getKey();
            dbObject.put(key.replaceAll(DOT_STRING, DOT_ESCAPE_STRING), value);
            if (value instanceof BigDecimal || value instanceof BigInteger) {
                dbObject.put(key + TYPE_SUFFIX, value.getClass().getName());
            }
        }
        Document updateDoc = new Document("$set",dbObject);

        getCollection().updateOne(dbObject,updateDoc);
            }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    private ExecutionContext getExecutionContext(String executionIdKey, Long executionId) {
        Assert.notNull(executionId, "ExecutionId must not be null.");
        Document result = (Document) getCollection().find(new Document(executionIdKey, executionId)).first();
        ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
        if (result != null) {
            result.remove(executionIdKey);
            removeSystemFields(result);
            for (String key : result.keySet()) {
                Object value = result.get(key);
                String type = (String) result.get(key + TYPE_SUFFIX);
                if (type != null && Number.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
                    try {
                        value = NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass((Number) value, (Class<? extends Number>) Class.forName(type));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.warn("Failed to convert {} to {}", key, type);
                    }
                }
                //Mongo db does not allow key name with "." character.
                executionContext.put(
                        key.replaceAll(DOT_ESCAPE_STRING, DOT_STRING), value);
            }
        }
        return executionContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected MongoCollection getCollection() {
        return mongoTemplate.getCollection(ExecutionContext.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public void saveExecutionContexts(Collection<StepExecution> stepExecutions) {
        Assert.notNull(stepExecutions, "Attempt to save a null collection of step executions");
        for (StepExecution stepExecution : stepExecutions) {
            saveExecutionContext(stepExecution);
            saveExecutionContext(stepExecution.getJobExecution());
        }
    }
}
```

Is this something related to deserialization mechanism changed for 'ExecutionContext' in version 4 ? Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: what steps have you "accomplished" to "upgrade from spring batch 3 to 4" ? *very curious*

Comment: I upgrade spring-boot-starter-parent from 1.5.2.RELEASE to 2.5.14 which upgraded Spring batch from 3 to 4.

Comment: That's cool, but obviously not enough... if applicable at all ... 1.: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide 2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNew 3. ...what else affected

Comment: also should keep in mind that spring-batch uses a (usually jdbc) "job repository" (which also might change with versions..)

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch 4 does not support MongoDB as a job repository, so the issue you are reporting should be related to your custom implementation.

The serialization mechanism has changed from v3 to v4, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNewSerialization. So this could be the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to SPRING BATCH in the custom implementation I missed to add the update option (set upsert to true)

Instead of just

```
getCollection().updateOne(dbObject,updateDoc);
```

Changed to below

```
UpdateOptions updateOptions = new UpdateOptions();
updateOptions.upsert(true);
getCollection().updateOne(dbObject,updateDoc,updateOptions);
```